# s60 won't start, no lights, nothing at all

Tags: electrical, battery, volvo

I accidentally left my keys in ignition overnight - and now nothing. Have charged battery and tried spare key, but neither fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you leave it turned on, or just leave the keys in the ignition? Do you have a DVOM (Digital Volt Ohm Meter)? What is the battery voltage? How long did you leave it on the charger and what setting was the charger on? How old is the battery?

Comment: not sure if left key on or just in. battery good - trickle charged, and showing full. i think it is security/immobiliser prob?

Comment: I don't think security will keep the lights from coming on. You say no lights etc, I take that to mean no dome lights, no headlights, nothing electrical works.

Comment: totally dead. nothing whatsoever. the security on the volvo is very good - can't help thinking it is something to do with that. the battery is good, and has never gone flat. it is fully charged.

Answer (score 3):

First step, remove, clean and reinstall the battery terminals. 
Check the fluid level in the battery (if possible)

Slow charge the battery on the lowest setting (not the "maintain" setting) overnight.

[See my answer here for more information on how to check the battery](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/406/if-the-headlights-dim-to-almost-off-when-i-turn-off-the-engine-is-the-battery-alm/412#412).

Answer (score 1):

it really sounds like a dead battery. If you are 100% sure that the battery has juice, my next guess would be to a) check terminals as Larry pointed out and then b) check the fuses.

Comment: will do. have reconnected battery well after charging- but will double check. i will loook at fuses also. will report back!