# Alternator vs Battery

Tags: battery, alternator

I hadn't used my car in a week. Normally it always starts. Then one day after one week it didn't start. I got a jump from my neighbor and i was able to drive around for more than 20 minutes. I stopped for about 10 minutes, turned on the car and was able to drive home. Next morning i can't start my car, I replaced the alternator about 2 years ago. Could it be the battery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could simply be the battery needs a complete charge, or it could be the battery or a parasitic draw. You need to have the battery tested to start. You can see my post here on [how to test a battery](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/412/85), or most auto parts stores will do it for you.

Comment: Hi Larry, I thought I completely charged it when i took the car for a spin, wouldn't that have completely charged the battery?

Comment: @Marin No, it's not the best way to charge the battery with the alternator at all. You should put it on a battery charger at the lowest rate practical. The Alternator is going to try and fast charge the battery which may not work well depending on the condition of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

20 minutes is not enough to load your battery. If you could start your car after you driven a bit, your alternator is ok. You could try to load you battery, but it could be, that it reached a low point discharge. If so, only new one will help. Also if the battery is more then 5 years old, just change it. Old batteries lose more and more power at the time.

Comment: So 20 minutes it's not enough?

Comment: @Marin, not at all. I would guess, it would load your battery to 10 - 15%. It would be enough to start your car a few times and only if the battery is warm. If it cool down, there is even less energy. To reach a 90 % of possible charge you will need something about 10 - 12 hours. For 100 % twice as much. This way is better to load your battery with special charging station over night or so.